# How to call a service method from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `service` and a `controller`. How can i define a method inside the service that can be called by the controller (passing a value)?

The following does not work:

```
angular.module('test').service('myService', function() {
    this.updateContent = function(selection) {
        alert(selection);
    };

    return {
        //required for some databinding
        model: [
             someProperty = null;
        ]
    };
});

angular.module('test').controller('testController', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.updateSelection = function() {
        myService.updateContent("test");
    }
}]);
```

Comment: remove the return part from the service and check :)

Comment: Registered and injected service name does not match. You register your service as `myService` and try to resolve it as `testService`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include the function in the return statement:

```
    return {
        //required for some databinding
        updateContent: this.updateContent,
        model: [
             someProperty = null
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('test').service('myService', function() {
    var service = {};
    service.model = { prop : null }
    service.updateContent = function() {}; 

    return service;
});
```

Comment: For info, although this would work, it could also be written in line with John Papa's Angular style guide - See https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y040 and https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y052

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: @HockeyJ I dislike these style - I dont like anything after return, I dont like using 'this' in javascript, I dont like local variables which 'lives' but has no direct declared reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `testService` to `myService`

```
angular.module('test').controller('testController', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.updateSelection = function() {
        myService.updateContent("test");
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In angularJS, there are some differences between **Services** and **Factories**.

When you are using **services**, you will get an instance of the function that you passed to your service, like a `new something()`.

If you are using **factories**, you will get the value that is returned by the function passed to your factory.

But, all angular Services are **Singletons**. The Service recipe is almost the same as the Factory recipe, but the injector invokes a constructor with the `new` operator instead of a factory function.

## Using service

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service) {

  //update by passing 'toto'
  Service.update('toto');

  //Retrieve object model
  console.log(Service.model);

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service() {

    var self = this;

    self.update = function(value){
      console.log(value);
    }

    self.model = {
      test: null
    };

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .service('Service', Service);

})();
```

---

## Using factory

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Factory) {

  //update by passing 'toto'
  Factory.update('toto');

  //Retrieve object model
  console.log(Factory.model);

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Factory**

```
(function(){

  function Factory(){

    function update(value){
      console.log(value);
    }

    return {
      update: update,
      model: {
        test: null
      }
    }

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Factory', Factory);

})();
```